# CakePHP AppController Components aren't inherited by Components during testing with ControllerTestCase

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am writing some unit tests for my controllers however I have hit an issue where by it doesn't appear that components which are defined within my AppController file are not being inherited in to my controller during testing.

For example, within my AppController.php file I have the following:

```
public $components = array('Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                        'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                )
        )
), 'Session', 'DebugKit.Toolbar');
```

If I go to the controller in question and use the following line of code within an action `debug($this->components);` I get the following result:

```
array(
        'Auth' => array(
                'authenticate' => array(
                        'Form' => array(
                                'fields' => array(
                                        'username' => 'email'
                                )
                        )
                )
        ),
        (int) 0 => 'Session',
        (int) 1 => 'DebugKit.Toolbar'
)
```

However, during a unit test the same line of code will output the following:

```
array(
        (int) 0 => 'Session'
)
```

There are no components defined within the controller itself so there isn't any thing there that is causing an issue, not sure what the issue is here or how to solve it.

Comment: Where is your AppController.php file? If you check `get_included_files()` during testing it's probably not your app controller that is loaded.

Comment: CakePHP/Cake/Test/test_app/Controller/AppController.php is being loaded as opposed to my AppController. Odd

Comment: Did you install CakePHP using composer and pear? Are you loading the composer autoload.php file?

Comment: Yeah, installed using composer and pear. I have the following line in bootstrap.php `require APP . '/Vendor/autoload.php';` so that the composer autoload.php is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't baked my application controllers so I was missing some lines of code. To ensure that the right AppController is being loaded the following line of code is required at the top of the controller.

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

Adding this line ensures the Class Loader knows to load the AppController, whilst the application would work without it, it is best practice to include it.

Comment: This was the solution I was given in the #cakephp channel on freenode - can't remember the exact explanation but was something along the lines of making sure the class loader knows which AppController to load. It doesn't seem intuitive to me and I would be happy if someone could come up with a better solution than this.

Comment: In fact the question I am asking here now isn't correct. The actual issue is why CakePHP isn't using my AppController in testing. Should I open a new question based on that or edit my original questions?

Comment: It did. The correct (i.e. the one within my application) AppController is called now when I include that line of code within the controller being tested. I agree it doesn't feel like the right solution as the application itself works with out this line of code - it is only needed to ensure that during unit testing the right AppController is loaded.

Comment: I see, to be honest I don't use the bake command enough so that is probably part of the problem - hadn't realised that the line of code would be included by default. I have been using the Cookbook to help pull my code together and there isn't a mention on the controller page about adding that so to date I hadn't done. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: +1. I was expecting [a rather different problem](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2620) - using composer with cakephp 2.x has some thus-far unexpected side effects.